# IIS7 Default Document not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7

I'm trying to set up a simple, temporary 'System Maintenance in Progress' page. On my local host (W2K8 IIS 7), I just add App_Offline.htm at the top of the Default Document list in IIS

When I drop the file into my web root folder and load the site - the App_Offline.htm page loads.  When I remove the file from the web root...Site loads as usual.

When I replicate this on our actual production web server (Win2K8 - IIS7 also), the App_Offline.htm never gets loaded.

The app is ASP.Net 4 and I do NOT have a defaultdocuments section in my web.config.

TIA - tom

Comment: Does the application run instead of showing the App_Offline.htm file?

Comment: yes - the app runs with the usual default home page displaying which is not in the default doc list - on my local host the app_offline page does load

Comment: I don't understand. Are you getting some default IIS error page or your ASP.NET application runs successfully?

Comment: on the web server the app does not load the app_offline.htm page when it is in the web root folder AND when it is listed in IIS7 Default Documents.  It works fine when I do it on my local host (development box) - i.e the app_offline.htm page loads when it's supposed to.

Comment: Does this help? http://kurtschindler.net/blog/post/App_offlinehtm-gotchas-with-ASPNET-MVC

Comment: No - I already have the <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> in my system.webServer section of web.config.  I figure since it works for me locally it must be some IIS config issue on the web server...the app web.configs are basically identical in both environments.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

The file has to be named `App_Offline.htm`, which it was on my local box, but we didn't have the same file name on the web server.